# Is this expression for root mean square velocity dimensionally inconsistent?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, dimensional-analysis

Root mean square velocity for the molecules of a perfect gas (as $P \rightarrow 0$) is given by:
$$c = \left( \frac{3RT}{M} \right) ^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

On dimensional analysis,
RHS gives $\left( \frac{[L]^2}{[T]^2[mol]} \right) ^{\frac{1}{2}}$ which must be equal to $\frac{[L]}{[T]}$, is it dimensionally inconsistent?

Comment: It is my mistake, I mistook M's units to be that of mass instead $Mass *  mol^{-1}$

Comment: You should delete the question since your premise for asking is flawed and recognized. It's not really about physics.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was based on a mistake that was since recognized.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't find an option to delete the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would imagine that you forgot that $M$ is the mass *per unit mol*, which would solve your problem. However, since mol is a dimensionless number, it arguably doesn't need to appear in dimensional analysis (though can be helpful).

Answer (score 3):

Working in SI units (equivalent to dimensions)
$$\text{m s}^{-1}=\sqrt{\frac{[\text{J}\ \text{K}^{-1}\ \text{mol}^{-1}] \ \ [\text{K}]}{[\text{kg}\ \text{mol}^{-1}]}}.$$ Alright?